# How to refresh data and the view of a table view in SWIFT for iOs less then 10

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a tableview. It gets updates from the cloud. Which is working but the refreshing under iOs 9 does not work. Reload does not help.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                self.tableView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
             // ???
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

How to fall back on the earlier version?

Answer (score 1):

Before `iOS 10` there is no `refreshControl` for `UITableView`. So we need to add it manually using `UIRefreshControl`.

Use like this :

```
class TableViewAController: UITableViewController {
    lazy var refresh: UIRefreshControl = {
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        return refreshControl
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.tableView.addSubview(self.refresh)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    self.tableView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
                } else {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    self.refresh.endRefreshing()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```